# How to re-install mongodb to my ubuntu 14.04 machine with removing old databases and old settings regarding with mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I removed mongodb from my ubunutu 14.04 machine and I installed again, but old databases and user authentication settings still there. I want to re-install as a fresh one

Comment: $ sudo dpkg -l | grep mongo
That should output a list of packages with mongo in the name.

Comment: following an apt-get remove mongo, try and run the command again with the --purge